# after redirected to appengine domain from custom domain its url also changed

Tags: google-app-engine, url, dns, url-routing

[image: dashboard]I have app in Google appengine ..and I I have WWW.mydomin.com. some how managed to redirect URL to myapp.appspot.com URL .when u click WWW.my domain.com it will change to myapp.appspot.com .I don't want to change my domain URL to apppot URL. I brought domain from net4.com ..I have seen red bus.com and many more sites which are running on Google appengine ..those URL doesn't change to redirected URL..is there any good documentation availabele for this ..thank u guys ...please help on URL forwarding with detailed procedure from scratch ...
[image: instruction from google]

I dint find any host in domain setting as per the step 4 ... pls explain about step no 4 .
my dns screen shots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you follow these instructions using an Apps domain?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain
What kind of redirect do you use?

Comment: rechecking but i am sure with that

Comment: Let me know is it possible to map www.mydomain.com to myappid.appspot.com ??

Comment: Yes, ofcourse it is possible. You do not need a redirect for www only for the naked domain : mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these instructions using an Apps domain?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain